# Unable to load full data on JSON with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, struts2

I'm trying to use Json with struts 2 and jquery, I am able to do it up to a level but I have been stucking in some problem for last two days. Here are the codes and configuration that i've used for this

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default,json-default" namespace="/">    

    <result-types>
        <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult"></result-type>
    </result-types>

    <action name="showUpdateAjax" class="courseCreateAction" method="showUpdateAjax">
            <result type="json">
                <param name="includeProperties">courseInfo, fetchedAllSubjects, selectedFetchedSubs, subjectList, fetchedAllExamType, examTypeList, selectedExmTypes, fetchedAllCourse, isUpdate, btnPressed, updateCourseId, nextCourse, previousCourse</param>
                <param name="prefix">true</param>
                <param name="ignoreHierarchy">false</param>
            </result>
    </action>
```

Here is my Jsp codes for this part

```
<tr><td><input type="submit" value="Refresh" onclick="refreshData()" id="refreshBtn"/></td></tr>

    <tr><td><s:a href="/SASIS/showUpdateAjax.action?updateCourseId=4">click Here 2</s:a></td></tr>
</table>
</center>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#refreshBtn").click(function(){
                $.getJSON("/SASIS/showUpdateAjax.action?updateCourseId=4",function(data){
                    alert('its working '+data);

                    });

                });
        });
</script>
```

And here is my java code

```
public class CourseCreateAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware{
private CourseInfo courseInfo;
private List fetchedAllSubjects;
private List<SubjectInfo> selectedFetchedSubs;
private List subjectList;
private List fetchedAllExamType;
private List examTypeList;
private List<ExamType> selectedExmTypes;
private List fetchedAllCourse;
private String nextCourse;
private String previousCourse;
private DAOInterface dao;
private String btnPressed;
private String updateCourseId;  
private HttpServletRequest request; 
private boolean isUpdate;

public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    request=request;
}

public List getFetchedAllSubjects() {
    return fetchedAllSubjects;
}

public void setFetchedAllSubjects(List fetchedAllSubjects) {
    this.fetchedAllSubjects = fetchedAllSubjects;
}

public List<SubjectInfo> getSelectedFetchedSubs() {
    return selectedFetchedSubs;
}

public void setSelectedFetchedSubs(List<SubjectInfo> selectedFetchedSubs) {
    this.selectedFetchedSubs = selectedFetchedSubs;
}

public List getSubjectList() {
    return subjectList;
}

public void setSubjectList(List subjectList) {
    this.subjectList = subjectList;
}

public CourseInfo getCourseInfo() {
    return courseInfo;
}

public void setCourseInfo(CourseInfo courseInfo) {
    this.courseInfo = courseInfo;
}
public List getFetchedAllExamType() {
    return fetchedAllExamType;
}

public void setFetchedAllExamType(List fetchedAllExamType) {
    this.fetchedAllExamType = fetchedAllExamType;
}

public List getExamTypeList() {
    return examTypeList;
}

public void setExamTypeList(List examTypeList) {
    this.examTypeList = examTypeList;
}

public List<ExamType> getSelectedExmTypes() {
    return selectedExmTypes;
}

public void setSelectedExmTypes(List<ExamType> selectedExmTypes) {
    this.selectedExmTypes = selectedExmTypes;
}

public List getFetchedAllCourse() {
    return fetchedAllCourse;
}

public void setFetchedAllCourse(List fetchedAllCourse) {
    this.fetchedAllCourse = fetchedAllCourse;
}

public String getNextCourse() {
    return nextCourse;
}

public void setNextCourse(String nextCourse) {
    this.nextCourse = nextCourse;
}

public String getPreviousCourse() {
    return previousCourse;
}

public void setPreviousCourse(String previousCourse) {
    this.previousCourse = previousCourse;
}

public DAOInterface getDao() {
    return dao;
}

public void setDao(DAOInterface dao) {
    this.dao = dao;
}

public String getBtnPressed() {
    return btnPressed;
}

public void setBtnPressed(String btnPressed) {
    this.btnPressed = btnPressed;
}

public String getUpdateCourseId() {
    return updateCourseId;
}

public void setUpdateCourseId(String updateCourseId) {
    this.updateCourseId = updateCourseId;
}

public boolean getIsUpdate() {
    return isUpdate;
}

public void setIsUpdate(boolean isUpdate) {
    this.isUpdate = isUpdate;
}

public String showUpdateAjax(){
        try{
        System.out.println("Ajax calling...........");
        showUpdateCourse();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }

public String showUpdateCourse(){
    try {
        isUpdate=true;
        courseInfo=dao.getCourse(Integer.parseInt(updateCourseId));
        System.out.println(courseInfo.getCourseId());
        selectedFetchedSubs=courseInfo.getSubjectList();
        selectedExmTypes=courseInfo.getExamTypeList();
        fetchedAllSubjects=dao.getAllSubjects();
        fetchedAllExamType=dao.getActiveExamTypes();
        for(ExamType exmType:selectedExmTypes)
            for (int i = 0; i < fetchedAllExamType.size(); i++) {
                if(exmType!=null&&((ExamType)fetchedAllExamType.get(i)).getExamTypeId()==exmType.getExamTypeId()){
                    fetchedAllExamType.remove(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        for(SubjectInfo subInfo:selectedFetchedSubs)
            for (int i = 0; i < fetchedAllSubjects.size(); i++) {
                if(subInfo!=null&&((SubjectInfo)fetchedAllSubjects.get(i)).getSubjectId()==subInfo.getSubjectId()){
                    fetchedAllSubjects.remove(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

I have used spring and hibernate in project as well. While doing this when I click on the link which is calling the showUpdateAction.action I got response like this

```
{}&& {"btnPressed":null,"courseInfo":{},"examTypeList":null,"fetchedAllCourse":[],"fetchedAllExamType":[],"fetchedAllSubjects":[],"isUpdate":true,"nextCourse":null,"previousCourse":null,"selectedExmTypes":[],"selectedFetchedSubs":[],"subjectList":null,"updateCourseId":"4"}
```

But when I click on the button its not showing anything, but the function is called. Moreover here CourseInfo is an object where there are variables with setter getter methods and this object is state full when the showUpdateAction.action is called, but in the output we can see the courseInfo is with empty curly braces. Please help to solve this problem I have gone through several posts and googled a lot. Now I have no option except asking. Please help

Comment: @mprabhat I did the changes but there is not much improvement, both of my problems are still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your replies Mr. mprabhat and Mr. Rahul. I used firebug to debug this problem, as Rahul told me to use webinspector for the purpose, as I am using firefox I preferred firebug. And I did really get help to solve the jquery problem as suggested by mprabhat.

Now, the actual problem was with struts-jquery plugin and spring. In my code for 'dao' the object is injected through spring. While json plugin was trying to serialize the object it founded a method of  the database object with public access modifier. Which somehow creates all the problems. I got an exception like below while trying to return the json without '`includeProperties`' param

```
org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException:  
org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException:  
org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException:  
org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException:  
Class org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter can not access a member of class  
org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister$3 with  
modifiers "public"
org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:230)
org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:160)
org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:126)
```

Therefore I decided to exclude the property 'dao' in my struts configuration instead of including the rest of the properties.

```
<action name="showUpdateAjax" class="courseCreateAction" method="showUpdateAjax">
    <result type="json">
        <param name="excludeProperties">dao</param>
        <param name="ignoreHierarchy">false</param>
        <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

And the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

As as starter on click of refrehButton why are you calling refreshData javascript method ?

```
onclick="refreshData()"
```

as you already have declared jQuery action for that

`$("#refreshBtn").click(function()`, don't have two listener for same event, please remove `onclick="refreshData()`, if required call `refreshData` from jQuery listener like:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#refreshBtn").click(function(){
                    //refreshData(); call this method here if you need to call
                    $.getJSON("/SASIS/showUpdateAjax.action?updateCourseId=4",
                        function(data){
                            alert('its working '+data);        
                        }, function(error) {
                            alert('Error here');
                        });

                    });
            });
```

2nd if your package extends `json-default` you dont need `struts-default` as `json-default` extends `struts-default`

Instead of `extends="struts-default,json-default"` use this `extends="json-default"`

3rd Also check if you are actually retrieving result from your database

```
courseInfo=dao.getCourse(Integer.parseInt(updateCourseId)); // Check if your object has field values
```

Can you please do these changes are post your findings

Comment: 1. I have removed the "onclick" from the button but its still the same, while clicking on the refresh button the method in the java class is calling but the result is not appearing as alert.     2.extends="json-default" is working fine, earlier i got problem while extending "json-default" only so i extend "struts-default"                                                            3. I put some SOL on the java code and yes its retrieving data from the database.

Comment: Are you seeing any javascript error ? And can you add error function to your jQuery.getJSON

Comment: Another thing to note here is <param name="prefix">true</param> is deprecated instead you should use wrapPrefix or wrapSuffix

Comment: Are you having another package with name SASIS ? You are accessing under /SASIS package and your struts configuration says namespace / "/SASIS/showUpdateAjax.action?updateCourseId=4"

Comment: If not try this  $.getJSON("showUpdateAjax.action?updateCourseId=4",
                        function(data){
                            alert('its working '+data);        
                        }, function(error) {
                            alert('Error here');
                        });

                    });

Comment: I did the prefix to wrapPrefix its the same. I have used firebug to see the errors response and all, but there is no error in javascript, moreover while clicking on the button actually returns the result like i mentioned in my first post, but its not showing as alert.

Comment: prefix thing shouldnt have any change just a better way, can you check the package name thing

Comment: I just did a quick custom check on my local machine with almost the same configuration that I have suggested and I can see my json being returned.

Comment: JSON is being returned in my case also but i don't know what's wrong with the callback part. As I have mentioned the firebug is clearly showing the return of JSON, its just not appearing as alert, and in JSON the state of CourseInfo object is not returned as well as other lists also.

Comment: I got something I got an error while debugging through firebug. Its "JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data

Line 2" I have no idea what does it mean, but I guess it will help me to track the bug.

Comment: @ mprabhat The Jquery problem is solved. It is showing the data as alert now. I put the following param in the struts config <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param> and remove the wrapPrefix praram. Now please look at the other problem why it is not feeling up the states of CourseInfo or other list objects.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at your code (no knowledge about struts) and I noticed,

```
<action name="showUpdateAjax" class="courseCreateAction" method="showUpdateAjax">
```

You ajax call is to,

```
"/SASIS/showUpdateAjax.action?updateCourseId=4"
```

I believe your controller is 'courseCreateAction' and action is 'showUpdateAjax' and a typical GET url would look like `/controller/action?param1=value1&param2=value2...`

But your url does not contain the controller.

The action to handle this request,

```
public String showUpdateAjax(){
  try{
  System.out.println("Ajax calling...........");
  showUpdateCourse();
  }catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return SUCCESS;
}
```

Where is the courseId being passed to showUpdateAjax() ?

Lastly, like mprabhat mentioned, you have already bound the button to fire an ajax call on a click. So there is no need to have a  `onclick="refreshData()"`

Comment: Since its struts no need to mention controller in the URL, Struts will find the controller using configuration defined

Comment: @Rahul Thanks for the reply. I've removed onclick="refreshData()" but its still the same. Rest is already explained by mprabhat.

Comment: Could you post screenshots of the network request, response via chrome's webinspector?

Comment: @Rahul thanks for the suggestion, I have used firebug to debug it and as i have no idea about chrome's webinspector. Anyway the Jquery part is solved, but the JSON is not filling up the states to CourseInfo and other List Objects. If possible please look at that part.